# Не удается создать файл командой CMD в docker

Tags: linux, docker

Есть такой вот файл `Dockerfile`:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Create hello world script
CMD echo 'if [ -z $1 ]; then echo "Hello World!"; else echo "Hello $1!"; fi' >> /home/test.sh

# Start working with that script
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash /home/test.sh
```

Успешно собираю образ: `docker build -t test .` и запускаю: `docker run test`. В ответ получаю такую ошибку: `/bin/bash: /home/test.sh: No such file or directory`. Куда делся мой файл `test.sh` ???

Comment: как **минимум**, вы явно перепутали директивы [`cmd`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) и [`run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run). у них смысл совершенно разный. вам явно надо заменить `cmd` на `run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что вы не понимаете как работает CMD и ENTRYPOINT. Если в двух словах, дело в том что при запуске контейнера выполняется команда ENTRYPOINT + CMD (именно в таком порядке).

[Подробнее можете почитать в официальной документации](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) или 
 [в переводе на русском](http://docker.cool/docs/docker-engine/engine-reference/dockerfile-reference/#entrypoint)